# No Such Interface supported while copying worksheets from source Workbook to destination Workbook - Excel VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop, excel-addins

I am trying to copy the worksheets from input Excel file into the VSTO Excel workbook. I am getting "No such interface supported" while copying the sheets from the input Excel file. If I use same workbooks of Interop Excel type, then copy worksheets functionality is working fine. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
    private Excel.Application _excel;
    private Excel.Workbook _wb;
    _excel = new Excel.Application();
    _wb = _excel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName);
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["sheet1"];
    _wb.Worksheets.Copy(ws, Type.Missing);
```

I have also tried to use VSTO Excel Addin instance to load the source Workbook file. It's launching the source Workbook on top of VSTO Excel workbook. I have to process multiple Workbooks by opening the Excel files silently without launching the Workbooks.

```
    Excel.Application excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Excel.Workbook sourceWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(FileNamePath);
    Excel.Worksheet xlWsSummary = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
    xlWsSummary.Visible = XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
    xlWsSummary.Unprotect("12345");
    xlWsSummary.Activate();
    xlWsSummary.Copy(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1], Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to use the `Globals` namespace to access the Excel Application instance:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["sheet1"];
_wb.Worksheets.Copy(ws, Type.Missing);
```

Second, if you develop a VSTO add-in there is no need to create a new Excel Application instance in the code:

```
_excel = new Excel.Application();
```

Instead, use the `Application` property of the `ThisAddin` class.

Note, the [Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbooks) property returns a [Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks) collection that represents all the open workbooks. So, you just need to copy a worksheet from the opened workbook to the existing one.

Comment: I have tried to use existing ThisAddin Application to open the Excel Workbook. But I need to silently open the new Workbook without displaying the Workbook on top of VSTO Excel Workbook. Is there any possibilities to do that?

Comment: Try using the [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) property in that case.